# Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: django

The following error is showing up even if I think there is no error. It worked very well but suddenly showing the following error "Invalid block tag on line 53: 'endblock'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

Instead of the codes I am posting screenshots
[image]

and here is the error page:
[image]

Comment: you have 2 {% block page %}  tag but only 1 {% endblock %} tag ??

Comment: In a hurry I just copy pasted twice I have only one {% block page %}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing a `{% endblock %}` tag for your first `{% block page %}` which causes the error.

Comment: sorry i just copy pasted twice

Comment: @KocielnyWizard have you tried using `{% endblock page %}`

Comment: yes I did but it didn't work. However, my server didn't recognise {% endblock page %}. For clarity I will provide screenshots. I am using pychram.

Comment: @KocielnyWizard you're `div` at line 53 is mising a closing `/`

Comment: No it's just PyCharm's shrinking this div element look there's + sign!

Comment: @KocielnyWizard There is something I don't get though. The code you posted and the two image are all different code. Am  missing something ?

Comment: Now I added the screenshots of the actual the code and the error page!

Comment: @KocielnyWizard Don't post the code as image. remove the image that contains the code and copy paste it. Just provide the good one this time...

Comment: Thanks for your effort, I just recreated the page wrote it from the beginning and changed some style. It worked!. I hope I made some mark up mistake. Thanks bro for your help.